# I can't see my TestCases in TestExplorer (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I wrote several tests in C# but I can't debug it since in TestExplorer I can't see my test cases. What is the reason and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please share the code for your tests, as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The tests should be public and should have the attribute according to your test framework, for example for NUnit `[Test]`. The class that contains the tests should also be public - for NUnit mark it as `[TestFixture]`.

Reference:
https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/test.html

Comment: I set up the tests properly but I can't run it using Test Explorer. I also have test marked as `Combinatorial` and they are also not visible. What is interesting I can see them in Resharper Unit Tests and everything works fine but sometimes I have problems with Resharper and I want to run the tests using build in test explorer

Comment: So the question is why there are differences between build-in test explorer and resharper test explorer